# How to call a function in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, function, templates

I have a function on my views.py file that connects to a mail server and then appends to my Django model the email addresses of the recipients. The script works good.

In Django, I'm displaying the model with a table, and I'd like to include a button that says Get Emails and runs this function and it then reloads the page with the new data in the model / table.

This is my views.py:

```
class SubscriberListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
model = EmailMarketing
table_class = EmailMarketingTable
template_name = 'marketing/subscribers.html'


# Get emails from email server
# Connection settings
HOST = 'xXxxxxXxXx'
USERNAME = 'xXxxxxXxXx'
PASSWORD = "xXxxxxXxXx"

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(HOST, 993)
m.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
m.select('INBOX')

def get_emails():
    result, data = m.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    if result == 'OK':
        for num in data[0].split():
            result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
            if result == 'OK':
                email_message_raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
                email_from = str(make_header(decode_header(email_message_raw['From'])))
                email_addr = email_from.replace('<', '>').split('>')
                if len(email_addr) > 1:
                    new_entry = EmailMarketing(email_address=email_addr[1])
                    new_entry.save()
                else:
                    new_entry = EmailMarketing(email_address=email_addr[0])
                    new_entry.save()
            

# Close server connection
m.close()
m.logout()
```

My main `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('marketing/', SubscriberListView.as_view(), name='marketing')
]
```

And this is what I tried on the app `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.marketing, name='marketing'),
    path('/getemails', views.get_emails, name='getemails'),
]
```

And then on my subscribers.html I tried this:

```
    <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'getemails' %}'" class="btn btn-primary">Get Emails</button>
```

But I get an error:

```
Reverse for 'getemails' not found. 'getemails' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can I call this function defined on my views.py inside my template?

Comment: Remove the slash (`/`) at the end. You should use the value of the `name=` argument, not the path itself which can change.

Comment: @Selcuk I'm sorry, I was trying some things and added that just to check. It throws the same error even without the slash.

Comment: That should have worked. Is that your main `urls.py` or your app-specific one? If the latter, please post the main one too.

Comment: That was my app url.py. This is my main one: 

urlpatterns = [
    path('marketing/', SubscriberListView.as_view(), name='marketing')
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not use app-specific `urls.py` files by default. You must [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#include) them in your main `urls.py`, for example:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('marketing/', SubscriberListView.as_view(), name='marketing'),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Assuming that your app name is `myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{% url 'getemails' %}` so:

```html
  <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'getemails' %}'" class="btn btn-primary">Get Emails</button>
```

> **Note:** Always give `/` at the end of every route so urls should be like `path('getemails/'...)`.

### Edit:

It seems that you are using `<form>` tag, so simply define in `action` attribute as:

```html
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'getemails' %}">
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying some things and added that just to check. It throws the same error even without the slash.

Comment: @chr0sy Can you please try `onclick="window.open('{% url 'getemails' %}')"` instead one time.

Comment: @chr0sy See edited answer. If you are using form so define in `action` attribute.

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I wrapped a button inside the form tag you mentioned and still says: 'Reverse for 'getemails' not found. 'getemails' is not a valid view function or pattern name.'

Comment: @chr0sy Can you share the template?

Comment: <form method='POST' action="{% url 'getemails' %}">
            <button>Click me</button>
        </form>

It's pretty small template and Stackoverflow comments aren't that readable. i just extend the base.html and then there's this button.

Comment: @chr0sy What about using `onclick="window.open('{% url 'getemails' %}')"` it should work try it patiently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249919/discussion-between-chr0sy-and-sunderam-dubey).